# a program that allocates huge chunks of memory using mmap(say 1GB)

Tags: mmap

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [suggest us on mmap system call operation that is able to access memory locations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5178988/suggest-us-on-mmap-system-call-operation-that-is-able-to-access-memory-locations)

my question is"how to implement a program that allocates huge chunks of memory using mmap(say 1GB) and then try to access random memory locations to read/write into it"                                                                  here is the sample program i tried:

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h> 
 #include <sys/mman.h>

 int main() { 
     int fd,len,mem_to_alloc
     char *p;
     void *mem; 
     while(1)
     {
         printf(“memory to allocate”);
         scanf(“%d”,&mem_to_alloc);
         mem= mmap(0, len, PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0); 
         if(mem==NULL)
             printf(“out of memory”);
         else
             printf(“memory allocated through mmap”);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

When this memory is allocated, how can I access locations in this?
Can anybody help me?

Comment: You need to use code formatting.

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5178988/suggest-us-on-mmap-system-call-operation-that-is-able-to-access-memory-locations/ edit your first question if you want to add informations

Comment: /!\ mmap does not return NULL on memory exhaustion but ((void *)-1), source: manpage.